# C++ template parent class constructor on child class

Tags: c++, templates, generics

I have this

```
template<class PayloadType>
    class Event {
    protected:
        PayloadType payload;
    public:
        Event(PayloadType payload);
    };
```

This is the definition:

```
template<class PayloadType>
Event<PayloadType>::Event(PayloadType payload) {
    this->payload = payload;
}
```

And this:

```
class SimplePayload {
protected:
    int number;
public:
    SimplePayload(int number) : number(number) { }
    int getNumber() { return number; };
};

template<class PayloadType>
class SimpleEvent : public Event<PayloadType> {
protected:
    PayloadType payload;
public:
    SimpleEvent(PayloadType payload) : Event<PayloadType>(payload) { }
};
```

Trying to use it:

```
SimplePayload simplePayload;
SimpleEvent<SimplePayload> *simpleEvent = dynamic_cast<SimpleEvent<SimplePayload>*>(new Event<SimplePayload>(simplePayload));
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
error: member initializer 'Event' does not name a non-static data member or base class
```

How can I properly construct the object?

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. That's what I actually had.

Comment: Your casting makes no sense. You allocate an `Event` object instance, it's not going to be a `SimpleEvent` whatever you say.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is to change the type of an existing variable. It's pretty pointless to use it in variable creation. It'll fail, too, because the argument (`new Event...`) is not the type you're casting to (`SimpleEvent...`), it's the base type. Just use `= new SimpleEvent<...>(...)` if you want a derived type, or better, a `std::unique_ptr` if you need the polymorphism or a regular non-pointer `SimpleEvent` if not.

Comment: The base class is `Event<PayloadType>`, not `Event` which is the name of a template. Fix the initializer list. Either way as it's been pointed out the cast makes no sense.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why? I'm getting started into C++...

Comment: where is the definition, inside cpp file or in a header?

Comment: I've updated the question. Definition in .h and implementation in .cpp

Comment: @DanielRibeiro move the implementation to a header file and all should compile and link...

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg that compiles perfectly now! Thank you!

Comment: @DanielRibeiro read the comments above, you can't downcast an instance of a base class.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. I was doing it the reverse way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the template argument:

```
template<class PayloadType>
class SimpleEvent : public Event<PayloadType> {
protected:
    PayloadType payload;
public:
    SimpleEvent(PayloadType payload) : Event<PayloadType>(payload) { }
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
};
```

**EDIT**

For the link error, try to move the definition to the header file.

See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: SimpleEvent(PayloadType payload) : Event<PayloadType>(payload) { } and  SimpleEvent<SimplePayload> *simpleEvent = new SimpleEvent<SimplePayload>(simplePayload); works but I end up with Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Event<SimplePayload>::Event(SimplePayload)", referenced from:
      SimpleEvent<SimplePayload>::SimpleEvent(SimplePayload) in main.cpp.o

Comment: @DanielRibeiro you haven't defined the constructor for Event<>.

Comment: I did, but like this: Event(PayloadType payload);

Comment: And the implementation is : 
template<class PayloadType>
Event<PayloadType>::Event(PayloadType payload) {
    this->payload = payload;
}

Comment: @SergeyA I saw that and removed my comment.  The op really needs to post real code.  All of these typos really makes the question a moving target.

Comment: @NathanOliver, agreed. This is why I downvoted it. Is that this hard to post **real** code?

Comment: I'm sorry, as a human I make mistakes. I've updated everything to the real code.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro It would be a good idea to post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of errors.

**Error 1**

```
template<class PayloadType>
Event<PayloadType>::Event(PayloadType payload) {

    // this->payload is of type PayloadType*
    // payload is of type PayloadType
    // Assigning to a pointer using an object is a problem.
    this->payload = payload;
}
```

The easiest resolution will be to make `this->payload` an object of type `PayloadType`.

**Error 2**

You are not using the template parameter when using the base class constructor from the derived class.

```
  SimpleEvent(PayloadType payload) : Event(payload) { }
```

needs to be:

```
  SimpleEvent(PayloadType payload) : Event<PayloadType>(payload) { }
```

**Update**

The OP's question has been updated since this answer. So, the first error is not an error any longer.